# JFrog Pipeline step fails with the error "Node failure"

Tags: jfrog-pipelines

I am facing this error in a pipeline run where we are using k8s dynamic nodes

The error message is:

> Step timed out due to node failure. This could have been caused by the
> node running out of memory. Please check the node stats and try
> re-triggering the step.

What do I need to do to get past this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix this, I tried to increase the k8s node pool’s cpu to 1 and memory to 2000 (2GB)

However, the root cause actually was that the node was not able to communicate its health to the JFrog platform. After 15 minutes of attempting to reach the node, Pipelines was marking it for deletion.

References:

- https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Kubernetes+Integration
- https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Managing+Pipelines+Node+Pools#ManagingPipelinesNodePools-AddingaDynamicNodePool